# using ftpWebRequest with an error: the remote server returned error 530 not logged in

Tags: c#, ftpwebrequest

I am trying to use the ftpWebRequest in c# 
my code is

```
// Get the object used to communicate with the server.
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://192.168.20.10/file.txt");
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

            // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("dev\ftp", "devftp");

            // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
            StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(@"\file.txt");
            byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
            sourceStream.Close();
            request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;
            request.UsePassive = true;
            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

            response.Close();
```

and I get an Error in request.GetRequestStream();
the error is: the remote server returned error 530 not logged in 
if I try to go in to a browser page and in the url I write ftp://192.168.20.10/
the brows page is asking me for a name and password, I put the same name and password and I see all the files and folders in the ftp folder.

Answer (score 18):

Shouldn't the line:

```
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("dev\ftp", "devftp");
```

be:

```
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("dev\\ftp", "devftp");
```

or:

```
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(@"dev\ftp", "devftp");
```

I have to believe this may be causing your issues because the \f is a form feed character.

Answer (score 10):

Faced the same issue, here's my solution:

```
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
    usernameVariable.Normalize(),passwordVariable.Normalize(),domainVariable.Normalize());
```

Details can be found [here](http://www.godwinpaul.com/sharepoint/2013/ftp-c-error-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-530-not-logged-in)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 7):

I found out that when connecting via .NET/C# to a FTP-server some characters are not "valid". After setting the login credentials to only contain letters and numbers [a-Z0-9] it worked to log in.

Comment: That Worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the double quote from username or password because sometimes $ sign in username or password causes problem. Its good to use single quote every time.

Comment: Don not post the same answer to several question. It is probably better then to mark them as duplicate of each other.

Answer (score 0):

If you assume anonymous logon do not set network credentials. this was the root of my problems.