# Error while uploading a text file to FTP server C#

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, stream, ftpwebrequest

I am building a simple application that uploads a .txt file to a FTP server. I have done this before and i am using the same code as i used for the other application.

this is my code:

```
string localFilePath = @"\\fileprint\data\Groups\Operation\fileExports\dls\";
string archiveFilePath = @"\\fileprint\data\Groups\Operation\fileExports\dls\Archive\";
string logFilePath = @"C:\Users\lmy\Desktop\Logs";
string ftpServer = "ftp://server:21/home/out2233/tmp";
private string logFileName = "" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString();

public void UploadFile()
{
    try
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(localFilePath);
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
            string modified = file.Remove(60, 6);
            string modifiedFile = Path.GetFileName(modified);
            FtpWebRequest ftpReq = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(ftpServer + modifiedFile));
            ftpReq.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            ftpReq.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
            ftpReq.UsePassive = true;
            ftpReq.UseBinary = true;
            ftpReq.KeepAlive = true;
            ftpReq.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("out2233", "password");
            ftpReq.EnableSsl = true;

            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(localFilePath + @"\" + fileName);
            FileStream fileStream = fileInfo.OpenRead();

            byte[] fileContent = new byte[fileInfo.Length];
            fileStream.Read(fileContent, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fileInfo.Length));

            Stream writer = ftpReq.GetRequestStream();
            writer.Write(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);
            fileStream.Close();
            writer.Close();
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ftpReq.GetResponse();

            AppendLogFile(response, "Uploaded Files: ", fileName);
            MoveToArchive(file, archiveFilePath + fileName);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
    }
}
```

But it get this error:
**exception = {"Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type."}**

when the code reaches this line:

```
Stream writer = ftpReq.GetRequestStream();
```

I have googled this but i can only find ASP examples. I cant seem to find out what i am doing wrong here. Hope you guys can help me.

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like, you're trying to list ftp directory content, with this line:

```
ftpReq.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
```

(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequestmethods.ftp.listdirectorydetails%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Try removing it, leaving only this line:

```
ftpReq.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequestmethods.ftp.uploadfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: This gave me a new error : exception = {"The remote server returned an error: (530) Not logged in."}
Am entering my credentials wrong ?

Comment: @Lahib, try solutions from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352165/using-ftpwebrequest-with-an-error-the-remote-server-returned-error-530-not-loge