# System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (530) Not logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net, ftp

I have the same issue as in this question: [using ftpWebRequest with an error: the remote server returned error 530 not logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352165/using-ftpwebrequest-with-an-error-the-remote-server-returned-error-530-not-loge)

I have tried the solutions there, but I can't get past it.

```
// Get the object used to communicate with the server.
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://<ftp-ip>/uploadFTP.txt");
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            request.UsePassive = false;
            request.EnableSsl = true;

            // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(<username>, <password>);
            request.Timeout = -1;

            // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
            StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(<file to be upload>); 
            byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
            sourceStream.Close();
            request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            //Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

            response.Close();
```

Where could I possibly be going wrong ?

Comment: I have the same code in .net framework
And in .net Core, in .net framework it works fine but in .net Core I get this error

Answer (score 3):

I removed request.timeout = -1. And, also UsePassive and EnableSsl, now it is working fine. Thanks.

I am not sure what the problem was but this is the final working code:

```
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://<ip>/<file_name>");
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

        // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

        // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
        StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader("<file_name>");

        byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
        sourceStream.Close();
        request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        response.Close();
```

Comment: Nice code but gives me a an exception that says: (530) Not logged in. Still looking...