# F# download text file via FTP with implicit SSL

Tags: ssl, ftp, f#, ftps

I am trying to download a file over FTP which is setup with implicit SSL. Here is my code so far:

```
open System.Net

let user = "user_name"
let pwd = "password"
let ftpLocation = @"ftp://*server ip*/*file location*"
let request = FtpWebRequest.Create(ftpLocation) :?> FtpWebRequest
request.Credentials <- new NetworkCredential(user, pwd)
request.Method <- WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile
request.Proxy <- null
let response = request.GetResponse() :?> FtpWebResponse
```

I am getting a remote server error:

```
System.Net.WebException occurred
Message: Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll
Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (530) Not logged in.
```

What am I missing here? I thought I passed in the credentials the way they needed to be. I am having a difficult time finding any documentation on this.

Comment: I found [this post on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352165/using-ftpwebrequest-with-an-error-the-remote-server-returned-error-530-not-loge), which points to [an article about this scenario](http://www.godwinpaul.com/2013/06/25/ftp-c-error-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-530-not-logged-in/). Does it help?

Comment: @Roujo, maybe but I don't know what it wants for the domain variable and I can't find an example of domain variable. What is this supposed to be? Is this supposed to be the ftp address?

Comment: @Roujo , thank you. That was one of the pieces that I needed to get this to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am leaving this here for the next poor person who has to do this. It took a lot of pieces from various places to get it to work:

```
let ftpLocation = @"ftp://*server ip*/path/to/file/example.txt"    
let request = FtpWebRequest.Create(ftpLocation) :?> FtpWebRequest
let user = "username"
let pwd = @"password"
request.Credentials <- new NetworkCredential(user.Normalize(), pwd.Normalize())
request.EnableSsl <- true
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback <- (fun sender certificate chain sslPolicyErrors -> true)
request.Method <- WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile
request.Proxy <- null
let response = request.GetResponse()
let responseStream = response.GetResponseStream()
let reader = new StreamReader(responseStream)
Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd())
Console.WriteLine("Download complete")

reader.Close()
response.Close()
```